# Warning output from Glassfish/JSF

Tags: jsf, glassfish

i'm getting this output:

```
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /ManagedBean, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
```

everytime a access a page of my JSF system.

Can anyone explain to me what is that? and why it happens?

Comment: @Xtreme: I'm not seeing a close vote from you? (which would autogenerate such a link). Did you manually create the duplicate link?

Comment: Mm not @BalusC, it must be an error. I created using the wizard..

Comment: Nevermind, you're still using flags :) It's only available to 3K users.

Comment: Haha that's what I was supposing.. Still have to wait!

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the answer but i try to locate the file `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml`. I tried add a new file with same name on WEB-INF directory but i´m having some errors. Any light?

Comment: Problem solved. I add a new `.xml` file on `Web-INF` directory, and between `<glassfish-web-app>` tags i put `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>` and works great. Thanks